# How to loop through inside a child node

Tags: python

```
<person>
<user name="david" password="super"><groups>meganfox</groups></user>
<user name="alen" password="boss"><groups>marvik</groups></user>
</person>
```

I like to get the text value of "groups" . but its getting always None.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc    = ET.parse("users.xml")
root = doc.getroot() #Returns the root element for this tree.
root_new  = ET.Element("person") 
for child in root:
    name                = child.attrib['name']
    password             = child.attrib['password']
for groups in child.findall('groups'): #this is not working for me :(
    gpvalue =  groups.text 

    user  = ET.SubElement(root_new, "user") # create subelement in cycle! 
    group = ET.SubElement(user, "groups")
    user.set("name",name)               
    user.set("password",password) 
    group.text = gpvalue

tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
tree.write("new.xml")

import sys
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

Output am getting :(

```
<person>
    <user name="david" password="super"></groups></user>
    <user name="alen" password="boss"></groups></user>
  </person>
```

There is no groups text value. its print only a closed groups. please check the output

Comment: You mean `print groups.text` returns None?

Comment: yes ,:( i need  all groups value

Comment: Are you sure the output is from the same code? I get this: `<person><user name="alen" password="boss"><groups>marvik</groups></user></person>`

Answer (score 2):

1) The entire block from `for groups` to `user.set("password"` needs to be indented one more level in.  Python's control flow is all about indentation, so this moves it inside the first loop.

2) Are you trying to preserve groups in the new file?  Once you have the groups value you don't do anything with it.

Comment: yes i need the same input xml to output xml : please see my edit with my wrong output

Answer (score 1):

replace `child.` with `root.` in your second for-loop! This should do it!

Or by the 2nd glance at it, it seems like you wanted to make a nested loop,
but your code isn't properly indented! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `groups` values without going via the users, you can use a path:

```
>>> root.findall("user")
[<Element 'user' at 0x1004d9f90>, <Element 'user' at 0x1004df0d0>]
>>> root.findall("groups")
[]
>>> root.findall("*/groups")
[<Element 'groups' at 0x1004d9fd0>, <Element 'groups' at 0x1004df190>]
>>> [g.text for g in root.findall("*/groups")]
['meganfox', 'marvik']
```

but the loop seems to work for me:

```
>>> for child in root:
...     print child.attrib['name'], child.attrib['password'], 
...     for groups in child.findall("groups"):
...         print groups.text,
...     print
... 
david super meganfox
alen boss marvik
```